# Can i invoke a method without using that dot operator

Tags: java

I have searched on many sites and according to them the answer is no,
Why does this prog in Java invoke this method without a dot operator?

```
class A
{

    public String toString()
    {
          return "Hello";
    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
          A a=new A();
          System.out.println(a);  
    }
}
```

Comment: @nneonneo, OP is asking about toString method.

Answer (score 5):

You have overriden the `toString` method of `Object`. All Java classes implicitly extend `Object`.

[Read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), although this would be a bit irrelevant to your question. See below why.

---

[You may want to see how](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) `System.out.println(java.lang.Object)` [behaves](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

---

And from there, you'll want to know what `String.valueOf(java.lang.Object)` does:

> **Returns**: 
>   if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

Comment: You edited the question ... to change the bracket positioning?

Comment: @Synesso My OCD told me so.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `println` method, it writes this to the output stream:

```
a == null ? "null" : a.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about how method got invoked without "."
Because in this case `a.toString()` is called *implicitly*

This behaviour is somewhat similar to:

```
Class A{
  void doSomething(){}

  void doAnother(){
  //both are leagal 
   doSomething();    //implicitly this.doSomething()
   this.doSomething();
  }

}
```

Comment: The `toString()` is not called by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

when you call sysout on any object refernece, toString method is called

```
 System.out.println(a);
```

As you have overriden this method to return `hello`, wour program prints hello without calling any dot operator.